# Filter by columns combination in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have two DataFrames "A" and "B". Each has two columns "key1" and "key2", but a unique key is a combination of two. I want to select from second DataFrame all rows with combination of "key1" and "key2" columns which are contained in DataFrame "A".

**Simple example:**

```
    A = pd.DataFrame({'a':list(range(20000))*100,
                      'b':np.repeat(list(range(100)),20000)})

    B = pd.DataFrame({'a':list(range(40000))*100,
                      'b':np.repeat(list(range(100)),40000),
                      'c':np.random.randint(4000000, size = 4000000)})
```

**Solution 1:**

```
    %%time
    A['marker'] = True
    C = B.merge(A, on=['a','b'], how='inner').drop('marker', axis=1)
```

*1.26 s*

**Solution 2:**

```
    %%time
    A['marker'] = A['a'].astype(str) + '_' + A['b'].astype(str)
    B['marker'] = B['a'].astype(str) + '_' + B['b'].astype(str)
    C = B[B.marker.isin(A.marker)]
```

*20.4 s*

This works, but is there a more elegant (and fast) solution?

Comment: If you set the index to `['a','b']` for both dfs then it's slightly faster to use `join` but not by much compared to `merge`

Comment: Well, that's pretty much exactly what `merge` (and `join`) are for, so I wouldn't expect to find something more elegant or faster...  I don't think creating the 'marker' variable is necessary (at least, it's not necessary for me, using pandas 0.18.0).  Eliminating the code related to 'marker' will speed it up a little more.  Also, you probably are better off using `%timeit` rather than `%time` as it runs the code more than once and averages the times, and a couple of other things too that make it a little better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try taking a look at `pd.MultiIndex` and using multi-level indices instead of plain/meaningless integer ones. Not sure if it would be a lot faster in the real data, but modifying your example data slightly:

```
index1 = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([range(20000)*100, np.repeat(range(100),20000)]) #former A
index2 = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([range(40000)*100, np.repeat(range(100),40000)]) #index of B[['a', 'b']]
s = pd.Series(np.random.randint(4000000, size = 4000000), index=index2) #former B['c']

In [93]: %timeit c = s[index1]
1 loops, best of 3: 803 ms per loop
```

The indexing of `s` with a different index (`index1`) from its original index (`index2`) is roughly equivalent to the your merge operation.

Usually operations on the index tend to be faster than those performed on regular DataFrame columns. But either way, you are probably looking for marginal improvement here. I don't think you can get this done in the microsecond scale.